# Vert.x run blocking handler before and after other handlers

Tags: vert.x

I'm trying to write a Vert.x Web handler that could be used to hide any processing latencies from an API to prevent figuring out existence of accounts as well as other information from an API. I would like to be able to just write something like:

```
    router
        .post("/uri")
        .handler(new LatencyNormalizer())
        .handler(new UriHandler());
```

In other words, make it as easy to use as possible and as easy to integrate into existing code bases as possible. Looking at the docs for `Router` and `RoutingContext`, I see only the following method as a possible candidate for implementing this:

https://vertx.io/docs/apidocs/io/vertx/ext/web/RoutingContext.html#addHeadersEndHandler-io.vertx.core.Handler-

I could then write code like:

```
  public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {

    long start = System.nanoTime();

    ctx.addHeadersEndHandler(v -> {
        public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
          long end = System.nanoTime();
          Thread.sleep(...);
        });
    ctx.next();
  }
```

Of course, this doesn't work, since sleep here blocks the thread. It looks like the handlers in the `addHeaderEndHandlers` list maintained internally by the `RoutingContext` are called synchronously, so there is no way to use e.g. `vertx.SetTimer()` inside the `addHeaderEndHandler`.

In other words, does Vert.x offer any interface that allows creating a handler which is called asynchronously before writing out to the wire (and with nothing written until the async call finishes)? This is for example how Netty works under the hood, which Vert.x leverages. I know I could implement this `LatencyNormalizer` as a base class for my other handlers, but it would not be as easy to integrate in existing code in that case.

Comment: you can use `RoutingContext.next()` to build up chains of interceptors

Comment: @injecteer: Your comment is not relevant here. What I'm asking is that if a handler in the chain calls ctx.response().end(), then a previous handler could intercept this and delay data getting written onto the wire. Headers end handlers are called at this stage, but the call is synchronous. Once the method returns, the data goes out. You can't set a timer or block with sleep, since you block the eventloop.